# How to replace shadowRoot in web component

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom

I need to be able to reset the dom in my shadowroot. This is in the context of Elm code that needs a particular dom node to attach to.

```
const oldDiv = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("div");
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("id", "elm");
this.shadowRoot.replaceChild(oldDiv, div);   // <--- fails here
this.node = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#elm");
```

My replaceChild command is failing with an error similar to this (`div` is a `<div id="elm"></div>`)
[image]

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: replaceChild replaces **existing DOM nodes**, your ``let div = document.createElement("div") `` is not a DOM node yet, only exists in memory

Comment: OMG, I had the params in the wrong order - it should have been `replaceChild(newChild, oldChild);`